# return atribute of an object in mongoDB using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using for first time `MongoDB` with `Java`. I think it is an easy question but I am not finding the answer.

I have a `collection` of `users`, with the next atributes: `username`, `pass` and `name`.

I want to save in a `String` the value of the `password`, by specifying the  `username`.

for example: I have a user `{"username":"UserName", "pass":"abc", "name":"Us"}`
I want to save the value `abc` on a `String`.

I have tried with the next code, but I am not specifying which is the `user` of the `password` that I want.

```
DBCollection table = db.getCollection("user");
DBObject us= table.findOne();
String pass = (String) us.get("pass");
System.out.println(pass);
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findOne` can take a query. See [findOne(DBObject query)](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findOne-com.mongodb.DBObject-)

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("username", "test");

DBObject us = table.findOne(query);
```

Comment: thanks for the response, it returns the correct object, but how can I save the pass  in a String value.

Comment: Isn't what you're doing working? `String pass = (String) us.get("pass")`

Comment: If there were two usernames with the same name, and two differents passwords, how could I save more than one passwords? 
                DBCursor cursor = table.find(query);

                while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                 System.out.println(cursor.next());
                }
I think that I should use DBCursor, but I don't know how to store it in a String. Can you help me?

Comment: jmarco10: `cursor.next()` returns a `DBObject`. So, doing something like `String pass = (String) cursor.next().get("pass");` should do.

Comment: awesome explanation. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

```
    //username must be unique to fetch one row
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("username","myName");

    DBObject us = table.findOne(query); 
    DBCursor cur = collection.find(us);


    String pass= null ;
    while(cur.hasNext()){
        pass= cur.next().toString();
    }
    cur.close();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(pass);
    String thePass= json.getString("pass");
```